# PHP Upload file into a folder

Tags: php, sql, html, forms, file-upload

Do you know what's the problem of this SQL code? THanks.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['resume']['name'])){
            $insert_data3 = "INSERT into applicant_other_details(`position`,`learn_from`,`work_availability`,`resume`,`date_submitted`) 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['app_position']."','".$about_job."','".$work_avail."','uploads/".$_FILES['resume']['name']."','".CURDATE()."')";
        mysql_query($insert_data3) or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Comment: what is the error you get???

Comment: I dont get any error but nothing is uploading into the folder or into the database. @habibulhaq

Comment: could be the reason.   dont use mysql_query as it is deprecated use mysqli_query instead.

Comment: I think your upload path not correct?

Comment: You can put the default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the mysql table design. Then it will add automatically.

I think you have disabled the error reporting or this block is not executing. Is there any if condition before this code? If so check if the condition is satisfying to execute the code

Comment: Here is a codition before that code @AbhilashCherukat -- if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

Comment: didn't work @habibulhaq

Comment: @user3803889 i am trying your code

Comment: When I removed the uploading process, the code works. @habibulhaq $insert_data3 = "INSERT into applicant_other_details(`position`,`learn_from`,`work_availability`,`resume`,`date_submitted`) 
      VALUES ('".$_POST['app_position']."','".$about_job."','".$work_avail."',NOW())";
     mysql_query($insert_data3) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: can you show us the form code?? I've tried your code and it worked for me.

Comment: @user3803889 - check your upload folder has writable permission.

Comment: <form><label for="name"><br>Attact resume:</label><input type="file" class="form-control" id="resume" name="resume"><input type="submit" ></form> @habibulhaq

Comment: You dont have a name for your submit control. SO if isset($_POST["submit"]) always fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="name"><br>Attact resume:</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="resume" name="resume">
<input type="submit" ></form>
```

if you want to upload a file you should use enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is  problem with your `form`.. did you include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form..?

When using `form` to `POST` data use this way

`<form action="post_request_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`in case your are trying to upload a file.